# Event Class, Event Listener and Abstract methods for JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Which event class, event listener and abstract method(s) of the listener will be implemented, in order to handle events on JCheckBox.

Comment: Check the [Java Docs for `JCheckBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html#method.summary) for methods starting with `add`. Note that it inherits many such methods from super classes - they're listed immediately below the section linked. More generally, for this type of question, *always* make the documentation your first stop. If you'd done that, this might have been sorted in 5 minutes.